# Magento: SOLR: How to sort autocomplete result of solr search

Tags: magento, solr, solr4

Is there any way to sort solr search Product result in alphabetic order? I'm using Magento Solr Bridge module.

Example:
Result should come like

```
Product1
Product2
Product3
```

Currently result is coming as like

```
Product2
Product1
Product3
```